# Последовательность ключевых слов в SQL запросе

Tags: sql, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Заинтересовал вот такой вопрос: имеет ли в SQL запросе значение последовательность ключевых слов. То есть, например, если есть в таблице 50 записей, то какую часть из них выведет следующий запрос?

```sql
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 40, 10;
```

а какую

```sql
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 40, 10 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Из [документации MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

```sql
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
        [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
        export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Остальные запросы описаны там же.

Comment: Спасибо большое - этого не надо было - надо было как раз наоборот :) Но информация очень полезная :) Весьма благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Первый запрос выведет 10 записей, начиная с 40й, а второй не выполнится из-за ошибки в синтаксисе.

Comment: Я уточню: результатом выполнения запроса будет 10 записей, начиная с 40й выбранные из первоначальной таблицы, или из таблицы отсортированной? И если нет - то можно ли это устроить методами MySQL?

Comment: Результатом будет отсечение отсортированных записей. Если вам нужно сначала ограничить выбор, а потом отсортировать (интересно, зачем это может понадобиться?), то можно использовать подзапрос: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 40, 10) AS tbl ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 1):

Последовательность ключевых слов в SQL имеет большое значение.

Все запросы, использующие неправильную последовательность ключевых слов, не будут обработаны.

Answer (score 0):

Второй подход можно реализовать с помощью подзапроса:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 40, 10
) X ORDER BY id DESC;
```